# how to query memcached for specific fragments and how to clear all of memcache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, dalli

Just getting starting using memcached with a rails app

I have the following fragment:

```
<% cache("home_main", :expires_in => 1.minute) do %>
```

and would like to query the value via the Rails console but:

```
 => nil 
1.9.1 :012 > Rails.cache.read('home_main')
 => nil 
1.9.1 :013 > Rails.cache.fetch('home_main')
 => nil 
1.9.1 :014 >
```

How would I query to get that fragment back? Or how would I see what the current cache keys are?

Also, how do I clear the cache?

From Rails.cache.stats

```
conn_yields: '0'
 bytes: '409071'
 curr_items: '23'
 total_items: '157'
 evictions: '0'
 reclaimed: '0'
=> nil 

>Rails.cache.clear

....
>Rails.cache.stats 
...
  bytes: '409071'
  curr_items: '23'
  total_items: '157'
  evictions: '0'
  reclaimed: '0'
 => nil 
1.9.1 :017 >
```

How would I truly clear memcached?

thx

Answer (score 0):

These are the 3 primary memcache methods I use:

Add a value to the cache:

```
CACHE.set(CACHE_KEY, CACHE_VALUE)
```

Read a value from the cache:

```
CACHE.get(CACHE_KEY)
```

Clear the cache for a specific key:

```
CACHE.delete(CACHE_KEY)
```

Hope this helps... Cheers.